# How to disable "Document Map" tab while exporting into excel via SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

When I export my SSRS 2008 report into Excel, I see there is a tab at the beginning called "Document Map". I do want to disable this tab coming from the ssrs export, but I could not find the way to do it. I appreciate if anyone helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If a report contains navigation links the document map will be shown when viewing the report, and a document map will be added when exporting the report. If you are exporting the report via direct URL access you can add &DocMap=False to hide the DocMap, though from the UI the only option would be to remove the navigation links.